# Textarea removes new lines

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form and when data entered, and submitted values get stored into the database by PHP. When textarea field filled with text for example:
Textarea value is:

```
A

B

C
```

Then I save this to the database and then display it, it shows up as:

```
ABC
```

All the newlines in the text section that added disappear. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: u can use before inserting text this      $text= nl2br($someText);

Comment: Unless you are actively removing the newlines, they are still there. This has to do with how HTML treats newlines and multiple spaces. Typically newlines are not translated to newlines on screen unless specifically told to. If you viewed the source, you would still see them. The easiest solution is to just use `nl2br` which will add HTML `<br>` tags where the newlines are which adds breaks when parsed. You can also wrap your text with a `<pre>` tag which is made to preserve whitespace and newlines. You can also use CSS and tell any element to preserve whitespace with `white-space: pre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because HTML does not explicitly form a line break with "newline" characters.

You need to use PHP's function [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert all newline characters in your text-area contents to HTML `<br>` tags.